# RelativeLayout does not fit everything in the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

While trying to add a `SeekBar` to a dialog box I realized I needed a `TextView` reflecting `setProgress()` of the `SeekBar`. I implemented it as such :

```
    private void customDialogTimeout() {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getSherlockActivity());
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    RelativeLayout input = new RelativeLayout(getSherlockActivity());

    final SeekBar timeoutSeekBar = new SeekBar(getSherlockActivity());
    timeoutSeekBar.setId(1);
    final TextView seekBarStatus = new TextView(getSherlockActivity());
    seekBarStatus.setId(2);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    lay1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    lay2.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, timeoutSeekBar.getId());

    layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

    input.addView(timeoutSeekBar,lay1);
    input.addView(seekBarStatus, lay2);

    ll.addView(input, layoutParams);
```

The resulting view however seems to "push out" the `TextView`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? If I am approaching this the wrong way please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SeekBar` has its width set to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and when you add to its left the `TextView` it will obviously not be show because it is pushed out of the screen(as the `SeekBar` already fill the entire width):

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay1.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    lay1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lay1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, seekBarStatus.getId());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lay2.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    lay2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
    input.addView(seekBarStatus, lay2);
    input.addView(timeoutSeekBar,lay1);
```